# TF26061: 'ColumnName' is not a supported reference field name

Tags: tfs-2015

I was importing the WIT file from our production environment to UAT. However I was greeted by this error "TF26061: 'ColumnName' is not a supported reference field name." and unable to proceed. Can someone tell me why this error occur and its resolution?

Comment: What's the detail code of WIT file? You can share it on the OneDrive. On the other hand, make sure there isn't the whitespace at the end of field name.

Comment: There is no whitespace at the end of the field name that's why I was puzzled what's happening. How can I share the WIT on the OneDrive?

Comment: Refer to this article to share file https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-OneDrive-files-and-folders-9fcc2f7d-de0c-4cec-93b0-a82024800c07?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: I realized that's our Production WIT that's why I can't forward it to you. But I can just show as snippet of it right here. Kindly see below for the snippet: <FIELD name="Column Name" refname="System.ColumnName" type="String" reportable="dimension"/>
      <FIELD name="Column Name Done" refname="System.ColumnNameDone" type="Boolean" reportable="dimension"/>
      <FIELD name="Column Name Lane" refname="System.ColumnNameLane" type="String" reportable="dimension"/>

Comment: What's the result now? Do you solve it?

Comment: It only introduced a new error. "Error importing work item type definition: TF248020: You cannot specify the 'Reportable' attribute for field 'System.ColumnNameDone'. You can only define the reportable attribute for Integer, Double, String, or DateTime fields. Remove this attribute for the field, or change the field type and try again."

Comment: You can't use Boolean type for reportable attribute, you can use Integer.

Answer (score 1):

Change refname to another name, such as Test.ColumnName. (do not use System)